# Trigger tag based on landing page

Tags: google-tag-manager

I am trying to fire a tag in Google Tag Manager that's based on the landing page (the first page of the session). What I want to achieve is that this tag is fired only when the landing page is example.com/landing-page/ **and** on every subsequent page in the session.

Hence, I do not want to trigger this tag on example.com/landing-page/ if the user landed on example.com/another-landing-page/.

I was thinking about storing the landing page in a variable that would be saved during the entire session and based on this fire the tag. But I don't know how to do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GTM does not have any kind of persistent memory, and cannot carry over variables from one page to another. So you need to set a cookie yourself, and look for it at subsequent pages.

The absolute barebones code for setting a JS cookie is:

```
document.cookie = "key=value";
```

which would set a first party session cookie with with the name  "key" and the valie "value" on the current domain. This might actually be enough for you (session cookie means the cookie would expire if the browser is closed, which sounds like what you want, else [you could add an expiry date etc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)).

You do not need to worry about code for reading the cookie, since this is something GTM does for you via the "first party cookie" variable type. Create a new variable of that type, give it a name, set the cookie name to whatever you choose as a name when you created the cookie and the variable will return the value from the cookie.

So you start with a custom HTML tag that contains the JS code to create a cookie

```
<script>
    document.cookie = "landingpage=true";
</script>
```

Next you need a rule to fire the tag.

You want to set the cookie only on the landing page, so you in your trigger you check for the landing page url. Also you want it to be set only when the page is the landing page, so you look if the referring url contains your own hostname (in which case it's not a landingpage):

[image]

Now that you have your cookie you want to subsequently fire tags based on the presence of the cookie. GTM injects its Javascript into your page, which means Cookies you set via GTM are first party cookies, so you can use the 1st Party Cookie variable type to check if the cookie is there by looking at its value:

[image]

Now you can use that in a trigger to fire your subsequent tags:

[image]

This might need some minor tweaks, but the principle is sound and it should be enough to get you going.

Comment: That sounds like it should work! I'll give it a go today and will let you know!

Comment: Okay I've implemented this as follows:

Comment: 1. Set up a custom HTML tag that only fired on a landing page and sets the cookie (document.cookie = "landingpage=" + window.location.href;).
2. Set up a trigger that checks if the value of the landing page cookie equals the landing page I'd like to trigger.
3. Used this trigger on the tag I'd like to fire on that specific landing page and all subsequent pages.

It doesn't work completely. The cookie is set as intended, but the tag is only fired on subsequent pages, not on the landing page itself. I thought this could be a timing issue.

Comment: So I set the priority on the cookie tag to 1 and on the tag that needs to fire based on the cookie to -1. But this also doesn't solve the problem. The tag is fired only on subsequent pages, but not on the landing page itself. Any ideas?

Comment: It is not fired on the page itself because a trigger requires an event (as in "event key in the datalayer") to be fired and by the  time the cookie is set the pageview event has already passed. You tried to solve this by priorit (I'm not sure negative values are allows). You should either try and use tag sequencing, or simply use the "Landingpage" trigger as second trigger on the tag you want to fire.

Comment: I added a second trigger to the tag to fire on the landing page and that solved it. Thank you so much for your help!